# Что такое .NET, и для чего он нужен?

Tags: .net

Уже продолжительное время со многих форумах, видосов, на тему программирования, я часто слышу про `.net framework` как его использовать на разных языках (чаще всего на C#), но что это зачем он нужен, и где он нужен я так и не понял. 
А и да стоит ли учить это дело учить, или это уже гиблое дело?

Comment: На все Ваши вопросы гугл имеет ответ. Насчет учит или не учить, это дело каждого. Работы по нему найдется, впрочем как и для большинство языков

Comment: Программная среда выпущенная в 2002 году в Windows для исполнения код. Грубо говоря, эта штука отвечает за запуск и выполнение программы в Windows. Учить или нет - зависит от ваших целей. Сейчас C# занимает топ-5 [согласно индексу TIOBE](https://tiobe.com/tiobe-index/).

Comment: Вот [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/components), объясняющая, что такое .NET и из каких частей он состоит

Comment: .NET это набор стандартизированых библиотек а так же виртуальная машина, для более удобного написания программных продуктов на разных языках (си# фортран# визуал-бейсик) как для Windows так и кросплатформенных. .NET библиотека требуется для работы продуктов написаных для неё.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Про .NET написано немало книг, так что в формате ответа на вопрос описать его тяжело. Тем не менее, максимально простыми словами:

---

### Что такое .NET?

.NET это большая многокомпонентная система (у которой, кстати, существует ещё и множество воплощений). Она включает в себя набор спецификаций (для внутреннего языка, IL, например), среду исполнения для этого языка (она называется CLR - Common Language Runtime, общеязыковая среда исполнения), базовую библиотеку (Base Class Library) - минимально необходимый набор объектов, многие объекты пространства имён System описаны в BCL, набор компиляторов различных языков (C#, VB.NET, F#, C++, JavaScript... Их действительно много, кто-то даже пытался [написать компилятор для Java](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jilc/)).

### Зачем нужен .NET?

Немаловажное свойство нета в том, что программу или библиотеку, написанную на любом языке с поддержкой CLR можно использовать потом в любом другом языке с поддержкой CLR. (Например часто встречается C#+F# в одном проекте).
Слово Framework в названии обозначает, что .NET абстрагирует программиста от компьютерного железа. Программист под .NET взаимодействует с .NET, а вся работа по оптимизациям, управлению памятью, вообще совместимостью лежит на фреймворке.
Кстати, запуск программы на разных компьютерах и даже в разных операционных системах - тоже одна из задач, которую .NET решает.

### Как используют .NET?

.NET широко используется в вебе на бэкенде (**Asp.NET**), набирает популяроность на фронте (**Blazor**), популярен в игровой индустрии, по крайней мере в сфере инди (**Unity**), его применяют в машинном обучении (**ML.NET**) и Data Science вообще. Абсолютное большинство приложений на Windows (как и значительная часть самой Windows (высокоуровневые её компоненты) написаны на .NET) для приложений: (**Windows Forms, WPF, UWP,** медленно набирает популярность кросплатформенная библиотека **Avalonia**), на .NET разрабатывают мобильные приложения (и Android и iOS) (**Xamarin**), и используют во встраиваемых системах.
Короче, на нём можно делать почти всё, если захотеть.

Важная деталь заключается в зоопарке реализаций и обобщающих технологий: .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard, Mono, а такие ребята как AOT компилятор в Xamarin для iOS и il2cpp в Unity. И многие перечисленные сверху пункты как раз отличаются используемым рантаймом. На эту тему есть [плохая статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/451084/) с неплохими комментариями.
Короче, тема сложная, но это отступление нужно чтобы ответить на вопрос…

### Стоит ли учить .NET?

Это сильно зависит от того, что вы хотите. Единственное, что я могу сказать точно - .NET Framework уже устарел и ему на замену пришёл .NET Core (актуальная версия - Core 3.0). Учить .NET Framework бесполезно, только если вы не хотите найти работу в какой-нибудь трухлявой корпорации, которая неповоротлива настолько что не может много лет переехать на .NET Core. Короче, если вы не любитель поддерживать Legacy.
А так - перспективные направления перечислены выше, и изучать что-то в этой области имеет смысл, если у вас есть интерес.

Алсо, 
[Изображение (устаревшей) структуры .NET [Википедия]](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/DotNet.svg)

---

Фух, коммент какой-то дикий получился. Я мог допустить много ошибок (сам я узкий специалист, но работаю на .NET), так что если кто-то заметит косяки - не стесняйтесь поправлять.