# Поделиться веб приложением (exe/dll) на удаленном компьютере/сервере

Tags: iis, blazor, публикация-приложений

Я установила на удаленном сервере `веб приложение`, чтоб с общего сервера иметь доступ, все корректно работает [тут можно посмотреть как публиковать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1509688/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-iis)

**но у меня вопрос:**

> Я копирую **всю папку проекта** полностью и это занимает определенное
> время,

> и уверенна, что можно сделать это короче, может только  `dll`
> или `exe`

То есть подскажите пожалуйста, кто уже делал,

❓❓❓

> какую **ИМЕННО** часть вы берете из папки вашего проекта и копируете
> на сервер после `publish`

для иформации ссылку тут оставлю, вдруг пригодится кому [Способы подключения к серверу](https://help.reg.ru/support/vydelennyye-servery-i-dc/dedicated/zakaz-i-nastroyka-dedicated/sposoby-podklyucheniya-k-serveru)

`Visual Studio => C# => Blazor Web Assembly => IIS`

[тут похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868778/how-to-deploy-a-web-site-on-iis-by-using-dll-file), но даже в комментариях пользователь все равно не получил ответа. То есть понятно, что нужно эти `dll` использовать но пошагово как это сделать ?

я не владею английским на должном уровне, а на русском когда переводишь, все так запутанно написано [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis)
я вот только папку `publish` поместила и работает, а есть ли интересно возможность, только `dll` или `exe`  ?

*** когда я публикую локально на свой пост, то просто подключаю соединение, публикую и все, я даже не копирую ничего. а если это комп на стороне, и их много, я разве могу ко всем подключаться ? тут я просто открываю удаленный доступ и заменяю старую папку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю вопрос больше про то, как надо накатывать изменения на сервер. А точнее какие именно файлы нужно скопировать после изменений.

Вы кстати не указываете, что у вас за приложение. Я могу предположить что это Blazor Web Assembly как фронтэнд и бэкэнд Asp.Net Core Web API. Вы можете опубликовать эти два приложения в одну папку через IDE или через командную строку. Результатом публикации будет папка, обычно в bin/Release/publish, но можно выбрать другое расположение, даже за пределами проекта, или вообще на другой машине. Важно понимать что именно в publish папке всё-то что нужно запуска, кроме самого .Net, но можно включить и его тоже.

Вы должны скопировать все файлы из папки после публикации. Да, на самом деле какие-то файлы возможно останутся без изменений, это зависит от-того чем ваша новая версия отличается от предыдущей. Как правило никто не отслеживает этот момент, проще выработать правило копировать всё. Можно использовать какой-нибудь умный инструмент который не станет трогать файлы которые не изменились, чтобы ускорить это дело, но это не всегда принципиально.

Так же, вы можете захотеть использовать так называемую [публикацию в один файл](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli), но конечно прям одного файла у вас всё равно не будет, да и для web assembly это вряд ли полезно, т.к. лучше иметь много мелких файлов, который кэшируются браузером отдельно. А для бэкэндовой части это вполне полезно и уместно.

Comment: почитала док, надо протестировать добавив тег `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>`  , далее пишется *Некоторые файлы можно явно исключить из внедрения* (а какие, а зачем ?)

Comment: по вашему ответу:1. приложение я указываю какое,  на 11 строке вопроса(wasm, api не я занимаюсь) 2. какой умный инструмент вы знаете, чтоб ускорить сравнение файлов. 3. Почему для веб ассембли это не полезно

Comment: *Важно понимать что именно в publish папке всё-то что нужно запуска, кроме самого .Net* а что значит .Net в данной фразе, и как его можно туда включить раз уж есть вариант

Comment: *проще выработать правило копировать всё*  по моему как раз таки проще найти один раз решение, либо какой то умный инструмент и понятие как им пользоваться, ну либо искать, потому что копировать все это по времени затратно

Comment: исключать можно, например файлы конфигурации, если предполагается их правка на сервере. Иногда исключают файлы SPA или другие файлы к которым нужен доступ, но вроде Blazor выделит wwwroot в любом случае. инструмент копирования в винде - xcopy. Включить .Net - SelfContained в csproj. Я имею ввиду зная ваши изменения, вы как программист можете определить какие dll и прочие файлы изменились, а какие нет. Но так никто не делает, потому что это не практично.

Comment: .Net это зависимости от фреймворка, а не те библиотеки которые вы явно подключили. Вы должны установить на сервер тот же фреймворк, что у вас в разработке, если не включаете его в проект.

Comment: файл конфигурации это апсетингс ? что такое спа. ( xcopy открыла ознакамливаюсь...)SelfContened стоит а фолс у меня,(где то видеда, ометила, и помему когда тру глючил)//я знаю свои изменения, а что какие именно файлы сомневаюсь всегда и беру и все хопом копирую, что мол а вдруг...

Comment: [вот как я публикую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1509688/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-iis) там вебконфиг мой есть

Comment: фреймфорки это рунтим хостинг, то что на сервер при ошибке 501 или 500 падает?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1016110/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-net-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd

Comment: SPA - это веб-приложение, в которых не происходит перезапроса страницы с веб-серверах при различных внутренних переходах. Чаще всего делаются на каком-нибудь JS-фреймворке типа Angular/React/Vue/Svelte, но также туда можно отнести и Blazor Webasm

Comment: да файл конфигурации, это например, appsettings.json